# Shuffling and un-shuffling an NSMutableArray (finding the correct index)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm implementing a music player into my app and when a user selects a playlist, they'll have control over shuffle and repeat modes.

Initially, individual `MPMediaItem`s of the playlist are stored in an `NSArray` (which is then handled by a function to play the music). When the user toggles the shuffle mode to ON, the array is copied to an `NSMutableArray` and the objects are shuffled (with the currently playing song at index 0). I'm good up to this point; the issue arises when the user turns the shuffle mode OFF.

Just like in the iPod music app, when the user turns the shuffle mode OFF, the original playlist is restored, with the location of the currently playing song in the original array.

Basically I want this to happen:

1. User selects track 5 of 12 in the playlist: Now playing Track 5 of
   12
2. User turns shuffle mode ON: Now playing Track 1 of 12
3. User plays presses Next song: Now playing Track 2 of 12
4. User turns shuffle mode OFF: Now playing Track 7 of 12 (where track
   7 is the location of that song in the original playlist, which was
   track 2 in the shuffled playlist).

I hope I've made this clear enough. I'd very much appreciate some guidance on how I should go about doing this in the most efficient way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an orderValue for object which you put in NSArray which will be equal to object index. So you can shuffle an array and restore original order according to this value.

Comment: Just to clarify, I should add `setValue` for the currently playing item, and with that I should be able to know it's location in original array? Could you perhaps give a short pseudo-code?

Comment: Yes. You can create you own class, which will consist music file path (or I don't know how you are doing that...), and additional value, like `NSNumber`. So when you put object references from class, you put it with it's own properties. According to this model you will gain accees (for example) to `[[myPlaylistArray objectAtIndexPath:i] orderValue].intValue` (I used `NSNumber` because CoreData framework creates this type for integer values in managed classes as usual case).

Comment: Oh I see your problem now. For your approach of turning shuffle mode you can set up `@property` value, which will store current song number in shuffle mode like increment. So max value will be equal to your `NSMutableArray` count. When user presses next button in shuffle mode you can just increase this property value and when user disables shuffle, you can switch player to song at this value index.

Comment: That wouldn't work as you cannot guarantee that the song belonging to that index in the shuffled array is the same for the original array. But your first answer has given me another idea of how to approach it.

Comment: Of course you should get access to original `NSArray` object indexes :) The easiest way to do it is just release your `NSMutableArray` and set up it one more time from `NSArray` without shuffling. If both shuffled and ordered songs will increase property value, you can switch to necessary position in any time. Or maybe I've lost some details of your main idea. Any way I am glad that I helped you even with another approach ;)